# org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException

Tags: java, appium

```
public class Admin     
{

    public static void main(String args[]) throws MalformedURLException
    {
        DesiredCapabilities cap=new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability("automationName", "android");
        cap.setCapability("platformName", "Appium");
        cap.setCapability("Version", "7.1.1");
        cap.setCapability("devicename", "HT4AXJT00193");
        cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.bcqms.cgs.MainActivity");
        cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.bcqms.cgs");

        AppiumDriver<WebElement> driver=new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(newURL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"),cap); 
        driver.findElementById("inputEmail3").sendKeys("admin");
        driver.findElementById("inputPassword3").sendKeys("jsmith");
    }
}
```

While I am writing the above code for authentication of the app I am getting the following error.

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. Details: The desiredCapabilities object was not valid for the following reason(s): deviceName can't be blank, automationName android not part of Appium,Selendroid,UiAutomator2,XCUITest,YouiEngine, (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: Please share the error.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. Details: The desiredCapabilities object was not valid for the following reason(s):  deviceName can't be blank, automationName android not part of Appium,Selendroid,UiAutomator2,XCUITest,YouiEngine, (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Answer (score 0):

Just update device capability name. you have written devicename instead of deviceName.

I had the same issue, resolved with above changes.

Hope it will work for you.